# ¿Porqué las dimensiones en pixeles no coinciden?

Tags: css

Estaba añadiendo un `background` en `CSS` pero no logro ponerlo con su tamaño original, se cambia de dimensiones por lo que se pone borroso.

Qué ocurre?, probé con porcentajes, pixeles y no logro hacerlo correctamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
    <style>
        body {
              background-image: url("client/img/backg.png");
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: 1018px 720px;
             }
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Pantallazo de web e imagen original]

Es error mío o del código?

Comment: Podrías enviarme por algún lado la imagen que mencionas para emularlo?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `background-size: cover;`?

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas conservar su tamaño original, no necesitas establecer las dimensiones de la imagen. Por lo tanto, sobra esto: `background-size: 1018px 720px;`

En este ejemplo uso una imagen de 200 X 300 px:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
    <style>
        body {
              background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
             }
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

No tiene caso agregar dimensiones con `CSS` ya que el navegador las detecta.

Si tu imagen es de 1018 X 720, se vería así: ***ver snippet en pantalla completa***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
    <style>
        body {
              background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1018/720");
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
             }
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

En este caso la propiedad `background-size` es innecesaria.